# How can i restore only Blogs from a SQL backup file?

Tags: sql, blog

I have taken backup of full DB from PHPmyAdmin. All other files have been restored successfully. But few blogs didn't come. Now I want to restore only Blogs. Please tell me how??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Blogs" or `posts` as they are called in WordPress are stored in the `wp_posts` table of your database. And custom fields related to your `posts` are stored in `wp_postmeta` table. So you should just be able to restore those two tables to get all your "Blogs".

This assumes your database is prefixed with `wp_` of course.